# How i can use AFHTTPNetworking for downloading and uploading images in ios

Tags: ios

I am using AFHTTPNetworking In my tutorial.

I have one OutLet of ImageView
and I want to show some images from server.

I have server url like this [link](http://My....Url/cr/z0501/GetImages). I have not worked with this and i am new in iPhone. Can anyone suggest me a proper tutorial for this ?

Comment: have you able to received image urls successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should read the tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial.
This is a tutorial is easy to understand about what should you need to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advice you to use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library. It's among the best library I have used for **Image** caching.
Import `UIImageView+Webcache` in your project and use `sd_setImageWithURL` method.